# Ошибка при компиляции sqlite3 библиотеки

Tags: база-данных, sqlite, golang

Сегодня переустановил Windows 8.1 и попытался скомпилировать код который экспортирует кукисы с sqlite3 базы данных, вот код:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"

    "database/sql"

    _ "github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3"
)

var cCook = "Cookies.txt"

func Sqlite3Cookies(cname, path, path2 string) error {
    wfile, err := os.OpenFile(cname, os.O_CREATE|os.O_APPEND|os.O_WRONLY, 0600)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    defer wfile.Close()

    var db *sql.DB
    db, err = sql.Open("sqlite3", path)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    defer db.Close()

    rows, err := db.Query("select creation_utc, host_key, name, value, path, expires_utc, is_secure, is_httponly, last_access_utc, has_expires, is_persistent, priority, encrypted_value, firstpartyonly from cookies")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    defer rows.Close()

    for rows.Next() {
        var cutc string
        var hkey string
        var name string
        var value string
        var path string
        var eutc string
        var isec int
        var honly string
        var lautc string
        var hexp string
        var ipers string
        var prior string
        var envalue string
        var fpo string

        err = rows.Scan(
            &cutc,
            &hkey,
            &name,
            &value,
            &path,
            &eutc,
            &isec,
            &honly,
            &lautc,
            &hexp,
            &ipers,
            &prior,
            &envalue,
            &fpo,
        )

        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
        if hkey != "" && name != "" && path != "" {
            var fInfo = fmt.Sprintf("%s",
                hkey,
            )

            if _, err = wfile.WriteString(fInfo); err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
            }

        }
    }

    err = rows.Err()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    return err
}

func main() {
    var err error
    err = Sqlite3Cookies(
        "Cookies.txt",
        os.Getenv("USERPROFILE")+"\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default\\Cookies",
        os.Getenv("USERPROFILE")+"\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Cookies",
    )

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}
```

Настройки go env:

```
set GOARCH=386
set GOOS=windows
set CGO_ENABLED=1
```

Выдает вот такие ошибки:

```
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../..
/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lmingwthrd
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../..
/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw
64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmingw32.a when searching for -lmingw32
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../..
/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw
64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libmingw32.a when searching for -lmingw32
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../..
/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw
64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmingw32.a when searching for -lmingw32
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../..
/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lmingw32
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../..
/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw
64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../..
/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw
64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0\libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../..
/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw
64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../..
/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lgcc
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../..
/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw
64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/libgcc_eh.a when searching for -lgcc_eh
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../..
/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw
64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0\libgcc_eh.a when searching for -lgcc_eh
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../..
/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw
64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/libgcc_eh.a when searching for -lgcc_eh
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../..
/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lgcc_eh
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../..
/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw
64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmoldname.a when searching for -lmoldnam ...
```

Если выставлю `CGO_ENABLED=0` будет выдавать:

```
Binary was compiled with 'CGO_ENABLED=0', go-sqlite3 requires cgo to work. This is a stub
```

Не понимаю почему так происходит, установлена версия Golang 1.9, пробовал на 1.8 и на 1.7, 1.6, все равно не работало. Почему так? В сети ответов и близко не находил.

Comment: Ваш Го плохо понимает вашу инсталяцию mingw. Попробуйте скомпилировать из `MSYS MinGW` bash prompt.

Comment: @biosckon уже понял ошибку, нужно было подправить GOPATH и перезагрузить систему, теперь все работает

Answer (score 0):

Если версия Golang ниже 1.8 -> нужно изменить переменную `GOPATH` на `%USERPROFILE%/go` -> `set GOPATH=%USERPROFILE%/go`, а после перезагрузить систему.